# Firebase DebugView iOS device name

Tags: ios, firebase, ios-simulator, firebase-analytics

When using Firebase's DebugView with an iOS simualtor, the name of the device is just "ios 12.0". How can we set the name of the device so that other team members' device names don't clash?

[image: DebugView iOS device name screenshot]

I've seen these two pages but they don't mention anything about changing the device name:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#device_selector
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382

Comment: can you paste what you have tried ? (code)

Comment: I've just searched documentation but haven't found anything